# How to Add 2 different submit buttons at 2 different locations on the same sitecore form

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am using sitecore 9.3 forms and I have multiple sections with 2 submit buttons on my form.

```
section1
section2
submit1 - send email submit action
section3
section4
submit2 - redirect submit action
```

This is the structure of my form.
Based on the user selection on section2 'submit1' button will show or hide.
on clicking submit1 it will send an email to customer.
If submit2 is visible and clicked it will give you a Thank you page.

The issue I am facing is on clicking 'submit1' or 'submit2', It is sending an email to customer.
while clicking 'submit2' it is not calling the submit actions added to that submit button, but it is calling the submit actions added to 'submit1' button.

Basically on clicking 'submit1' or 'submit2' it is calling submit1 submit action.

Is there any way we can have 2 different submit buttons on a single sitecore form.

Comment: Do your buttons have different field names?

Comment: yes, they have different field names.

Comment: Have you tried tinkering with the submit actions? What happens if you change one of the submit actions to "Redirect to Page"? Same issue?

Comment: yes, I tried it. what ever the submit actions are added for 'submit1'. They are getting executed every time.

Comment: The first submit button on the form is executed. irrespective of clicking submit1 or submit2.

Comment: Are you using the forms extensions module?

Comment: I am not aware of forms extensions.

Comment: Is your send email submit action the default "Send Email Campaign Message"? Or is it a custom built submit action?

Comment: It is a custom built submit action.

Comment: Is the issue replicable in all browsers?